# Add a class from array if propery matches name attribute in list element

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form with multiple "blocks", like this:
[image: form]

and on the left I have like a sidebar where every block number matches a number in the sidebar. If there are any errors, a class is added to each li element. The sidebar is basically just a unordered list (not from an array) and have a name attribute that also matches the name of the block :

```
    <ul>
     <li name="Personal information">1</li>
     <li name="Employment">2</li>
      //rest of the li elements
   </ul>
```

[image: sidebar]

The valdation is done from backend and I get an array with objects with the errors that look like this:

```
[
    {
        "Message": "Name is required",
        "Type": "Error",
        "Field": "Employment"
    },
    {
        "Message": "Date must start...",
        "Type": "Warning",
        "Field": "Personal Information",
    },

]
```

I'm struggeling how to add the classes for the sidebar without doing alot of if statements (there are 16 blocks in the form).

- I have to check if the property `Field` in error array matches the name attribute in sidebar, then add class if it exists.
- The class sholud be equal to the `Type` propery in error array.
- If theres no errors for that name then add class `valid`.

Any ideas how to do this the best way?

Comment: You need to create one Component (It has a number and an icon) and you give the date in your array to it. So you need only one component with the if conditions. And this component you can use as sidebar inside `ngFor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a simple function to check for errors:

```js
getValidationType(errors, field) {
  return errors.find(error => error.field === field)?.Type ?? 'valid';
}
```

and then call it in the template:

```html
<li name="Personal information" [class]="getValidationType(errorArray, 'Personal information')">1</li>
```

You could also create an array with all fields and iterate through it:

```js
fields = [
  'Personal information',
  'Employment',
  // etc...
];
```

and then iterate through it in your template:

```html
<ul>
    <li 
        *ngFor="let field of fields; let i = index"
        [name]="field"
        [class]="getValidationType(errorArray, field)"
    >
        {{ i + 1 }}
    </li>
</ul>
```